# Add Reaction to a message in discord.py

Tags: python, discord

I am trying to add a reaction to an command as a *response* instead of a text. However i haven't found anything, that would get close to solving my issue. If anybody could help me, i would be very grateful.

BTW: I apologise for my bad english. It isn't my native language.

Comment: Please share the code you used, so we can better understand your problem and what you have done so far.